# How to logout from a particular project using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I am trying to logout from only one project but the problem is when i am running two web project in browser at a time. After login in both, i click logout button of 1st project but both project's Sessions ends automatically on logout button click of any one.

For log out i am using `Session.Abandon();`.

I am using visual studio 2012, can i logout from only one project?

Here is my login code

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    qry = "select * from UserTable where Uname='" + txtUname.Text + "' and Pwd='" + txtPwd.Text + "' ";
    com = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
    dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Session["UName"] = txtUname.Text;
        Session["Pwd"] = txtPwd.Text;
        Session["Name"] = dr["Name"].ToString();
        Session["Mail"] = dr["Mail"].ToString();
        if (chkStayLogin.Checked)
        {
            Response.Cookies["rsstl"]["stul_"] = crypt.Encrypt(uname);
            Response.Cookies["rsstl"]["stpl_"] = crypt.Encrypt(pwd);
            Response.Cookies["rsstl"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Cookies["rsstl"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        }
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblLogin.Visible = true;
        lblLogin.Text = "Enter Valid User Name And Password";
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

and my logout code

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cki = new HttpCookie("rsstl");
    cki.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cki);
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```

I am using same code in other project.

Comment: It is all depends on how you login to sites. Please upload the code of login. If you use **form authentication**, please also post **authentication** tag inside web.config.

Comment: Now i have added login and logout code in the question

Comment: How do you differentiate login between two sites? Are they hosted same domain name such as **site1.mysite.com** and **site2.mysite.com**? Is this single-sign-on? **Is this a school project?**

Comment: sorry sir i was not mention that i am trying this on my localhost. 1st project is my summer training project (Online Railway Ticket Booking) and 2nd one is my final year project (Online Examination System) and is there any problem when i will host these two on same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am trying this on my localhost. 1st project is my summer training
>   project (Online Railway Ticket Booking) and 2nd one is my final year
>   project (Online Examination System) and is there any problem when i
>   will host these two on same domain?

According to the above comment, both sites' cookies are same and stored under same domain name which is localhost.

As the result, when a user logs out from **site 1**, s/he will be automatically logout from site 2 since they are sharing the same cookie.

In order to avoid that, you'll need to store two different cookie names. For example

```
Response.Cookies["rsstl" + site1]["stul_"] = crypt.Encrypt(uname);
Response.Cookies["rsstl" + site1]["stpl_"] = crypt.Encrypt(pwd);
```

### Other thoughts

1. Use parameterized query to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
2. [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could be a lot easier than what you are currently doing. *However, it is out of the scope of your original question.*

Comment: Very very Thanks to you sir now it is working fine and also i will modify my both project to stored procedure. Thanks again sir.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, please mark it as Answer. It'll help others who look for the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

try to run in IE in new session

```
File -> new session
```